# In Jmeter's TCP Sampler: what's the difference between no "Re-use connection" vs "Re-use + Close connection"?

Tags: tcp, jmeter

I'm new to using JMeter, and I found that in the TCP Sampler (Jmeter version 2.11) there are 2 checkboxes labeled "Re-use Connection" and "Close Connection". So the documentation says this:

> Re-use connection: If selected, the connection is kept open. Otherwise it is closed when the data has been read.
>
> Close connection: If selected, the connection will be closed after running the sampler.

So from what I understand, it is the same to not check Re-use Connection than to check both Re-use Connection and Close Connection, is it? Then what's the point of checking both?

Answer (score 1):

Basically each thread group can have several threads running under it, so the re-use mean It get reused. Please read the following explanation.

> If "Re-use connection" is selected, connections are shared between Samplers in the same thread, provided that the exact same host name string and port are used. Different hosts/port combinations will use different connections, as will different threads. If both of "Re-use connection" and "Close connection" are selected, the socket will be closed after running the sampler. On the next sampler, another socket will be created. You may want to close a socket at the end of each thread loop. If an error is detected - or "Re-use connection" is not selected - the socket is closed. Another socket will be reopened on the next sample.